# Where does ion-new-view begin to look for first state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic-view

I cant seem to find any documentation on how ion-nav-view loads its first template. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: its your default route

Comment: @entre i have posted my code below

Comment: the otherwise part in below case

Comment: I have just tried that and it still gives me a blank page. I think it is not configured properly. I have posted the code below. Thank you for the help @entre

Comment: url shouldnot be index.html

Answer (score 0):

Does default mean it will see my findEvents state and load that template first? @entre

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers',     'ionic.contrib.ui.tinderCards'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory  bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins &&     window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
        // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
        StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
});
})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

 .state('FindEvents', {
     url: 'index.html',
     templateUrl: 'templates/events.html',
     controller: 'EventsCtrl'
 }
 )

.state('favorites', {
    url: '/favorites',
    templateUrl: 'templates/favorites.html',
    controller: 'FavoritesCtrl'
})

//alert("working");
// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/findEvents')

});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>SlidingTransitionwithAPI</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"> </script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/ionic-ion-swipe-cards/ionic.swipecards.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/collide/collide.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-ion-tinder-cards/ionic.tdcards.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-app="starter" no-scroll>
    <ion-nav-view>

    </ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

controllers.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.directive('noScroll', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
        $element.on('touchmove', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
}
})


.controller('EventsCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
var cardTypes = [
    { image: './images/event1.jpeg', title: 'New Apple Release' },
    { image: './images/event2.jpeg', title: 'Digital Conference' },
    { image: './images/event3.jpg', title: 'Skyline Sessions' },
    { image: './images/event4.jpg', title: 'Secret Rooftop Party' },
    { image: './images/event5.jpeg', title: 'Smoking Lights' },
    { image: './images/event6.jpg', title: 'Antibes Color Run' },
    { image: './images/event7.jpg', title: 'Tomorrowland' },
    { image: './images/event8.jpeg', title: 'Steve Aoki Lighting Up Town' },
    { image: './images/event9.jpeg', title: 'Nice Yacht Party' },
    { image: './images/event10.jpg', title: 'Night Pool Party' },

];

$scope.cards = [];

$scope.addCard = function () {
    for (var p = 0; p < 10; p++) {

        var newCard = cardTypes[p];
        newCard.id = Math.random();
        $scope.cards.push(angular.extend({}, newCard));
    }
}

$scope.addCard();

$scope.cardDestroyed = function (index) {
    $scope.cards.splice(index, 1);
};

$scope.cardSwipedLeft = function (index) {
    console.log('Left swipe');
}

$scope.cardSwipedRight = function (index) {
    console.log('Right swipe');
}

$scope.cardDestroyed = function (index) {
    $scope.cards.splice(index, 1);
    console.log('Card removed');
}

//Transitioning between states
$scope.Favorites = function () {

    $state.go('favorites');
}
});
```

events.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Events" ng-controller="EventsCtrl">

<ion-content ng-app="starter" >
    <ion-pane>
        <div class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
            <button class="button button-clear button-icon icon ion-navicon"> </button>
            <div class="h1 title" font="6" color="white">Event Finder</div>
            <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="Favorites()">
                <i class="icon ion-heart"></i>
            </button>
        </div>

        <td-cards>
            <td-card id="td-card" ng-repeat="card in cards" on-destroy="cardDestroyed($index)"
                     on-swipe-left="cardSwipedLeft($index)" on-swipe-  right="cardSwipedRight($index)"
                     on-partial-swipe="cardPartialSwipe(amt)">
                <div class="title">
                    {{card.title}}
                </div>
                <div class="image">
                    <div class="no-text overlayBox"><div class="noBox boxed">Trash</div></div>
                    <img ng-src="{{card.image}}">
                    <div class="yes-text overlayBox"><div class="yesBox boxed" id="centerMe">Save</div></div>
                </div>
            </td-card>
        </td-cards>
    </ion-pane>

</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I think you uploaded code to enhance question so you should have pasted this code by editing your question instead of adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `app.js` config block should be:

```
$stateProvider

 .state('FindEvents', {
     url: 'findEvents',
     templateUrl: 'templates/events.html',
     controller: 'EventsCtrl'
 })

.state('favorites', {
    url: '/favorites',
    templateUrl: 'templates/favorites.html',
    controller: 'FavoritesCtrl'
})

//alert("working");
// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/findEvents')
```

`url` of `FindEvents` state should be `findEvents` and not `index.html`. `url` is not a reference to any html file but a string that you'll use to identify the route.

It is not easy to identify issues with `angular-ui-router` due to lots of configuration. You can make use of this [FAQ's suggestion](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-im-getting-a-blank-screen-and-there-are-no-errors) for any future related issues.

Comment: Thanks Ritesh. I did try that and it still is not working. The default template is not being complied leaving me with a white screen @Ritesh Jagga